# Possible number of codes..?

Tags: combinatorics

A combination lock consisting of 0-100 So 101 digits,  and the Combination lock has 3 number turn dial safe lock codes.  What are the number of possible codes.?  Including repeat numbers. Examples: 07-19-69.   Or 26-34-26  or 00-69-00.  I'm curious on how may possible codes can there be with a digit Lock, having 0-100 .   Can Anyone Answer. .?   Thank you.

Comment: Each digit has $101$ possibilities, hence three would have $101^3$ possibilities. You might want to use appropriate grammar for the statement '0-100 So 101 digits' as it is more than a little confusing.

Comment: If the lock is mechanical, then it is possible the lock has some mechanical tolerance of $\pm 2$. So to open a safe, you only need $21^3 \approx 9000$ instead of a million trials. This is how Richard Feymann crack all those safes in Los Almos during the war.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simpler example; let's say the numbers used can be only $0$ or $1$.

Then we can have the following combinations:

\begin{align} &0-0-0 \\
&0-0-1 \\
&0-1-0 \\
&1-0-0 \\
&0-1-1 \\
&1-0-1 \\
&1-1-0 \\
&1-1-1 \\
\end{align}

In that example we had $2$ possibilities and $3$ numbers to place, and the number of combinations were $2^3=8$. This generalises, so using the numbers in your question, we have $101^3=1030301$ different combinations.

Think about it like this: We have to put three numbers down. In choosing the first we have $101$ possibilities. For each one of them, we have to chose a second number, so now we have $101^2$ possibilities. But for all of these, we have to choose a third number as well. Thus we end at $101^3$.